# MongoDB query optimization ($lookup)

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I want to get a specific user's recently updated `threads` and the `member` document of it. My query does extra job, it gets `threads` through `$lookup` for each `member` document and checks if the `thread` matches the condition: `{ $gt: ["$updated_at", timestamp] }`, **How to optimize the query?**

I could add `updated_at` to the `member` but a `update` query is needed for a large number of documents (200,000 or 2,000,000) every time the threads gets updated, about every 2 seconds. **How long does it take to update the documents?**

| Member | Thread |
| --- | --- |
| _id | _id |
| thread_id | title |
| user_id | updated_at |
| deleted | destroyed |

My query:

```js
const user_id = 4;
const timestamp = 1611011380321;
const data = await Member.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      user_id,
      deleted: false
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "threads",
      let: {
        thread_id: "$thread_id",
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: ["$_id", "$$thread_id"] },
                { $eq: ["$destroyed", false] },
                { $gt: ["$updated_at", timestamp] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "thread"
    }
  },
  { $sort: { "$thread.updated_at": -1 },
  { $limit: 10 }  
]);
```

Comment: what you want? there are multiple questions? you need to optimize existing query? or you need to optimize schema design and as per new schema you need to do update operation?

Comment: @turivishal Optimization of the query, or Optimization of the schema if possible, I'm looking for the best way.